# OpenOffice SQL query date selection

Tags: sql, hsqldb, openoffice-base, frontbase

I've been searching the web and asked around, but can't seem to find an answer to my problem...

I have a running ODBC connection with my FrontBase database in OpenOffice Base. I manage to select everything I want, but when I only want to show the records between certain dates, or even one date I keep on getting a Semantic Error.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM "SALES" WHERE "DATE" = '2014-04-01'
```

Just in case you suggest using `#` for the date, it doesn't work either

`DATE '2014-04-01'` is also unsuccessful :(

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try with  WHERE "DATE" >= '2014-04-01' and similar to eliminate any possible issues with daylight saving hours. You should also report the error that is returned.

Comment: @fredt Unfortunately no success. I get the following error:
SQL-status: HY000

[FrontBase Inc.][FrontBase ODBC]Semantic error 217. Datatypes are not comparable or don't match.
Semantic error 485. Near: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM "SALES" WHERE "DATE">='2014-04-01';.
Semantic error 485. Near: '2014-04-01'.
Exception 363. Transaction rollback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of trial and errors I took a closer look at the OpenOfficeBase interface. I was sure nothing was wrong with my statement so there must be something in Base that I'm missing.

In the toolbar there's a button with SQL and a checkmark which says "Execute SQL-command immediatly". Thought it wouldn't do any harm if I enabled it and gave it a try. And there it was, my query with date filter! I have no idea why that button is there or what it's exact function is, but enabling it made my query work.

[image]

Thanks anyway for the suggestions, but apparently we've got to look further than just the language ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark here. Youŕe using a FrontBase database, googling on "Frontbase select date range" gave me this page: http://www.frontbase.com/documentation/LookSeeIntro-2.3.html

There they have this example query:

```
SELECT
   receiver FROM memo_mails 
WHERE 
   sender = 'QA' AND 
   CAST(dateSent AS DATE) < DATE '2001-06-01' AND
   SATISFIES(quickx, 'Periscope & invoice');
```

So based on that example, I would try

```
SELECT
    * FROM "Sales"
WHERE
    (CAST("Sales"."SalesDate" AS DATE) >= DATE '2014-06-01') AND
    (CAST("Sales"."SalesDate" AS DATE) <= DATE '2014-06-30');
```

Comment: I found that one too during my quest, but since it contains DATE I immediately get "Syntax error in SQL expression".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM SALES WHERE DATE = '2014-04-01'
```

The above should work as long as there is no time in the column you are trying to select from. Whats the columns data type?

Comment: It's a simple Date column without any time stamps. When you view the table it's formatted as 01/04/2014, but of course that doesn't work either in the query...

Answer (score -1):

If you're still looking for answers

`SELECT * FROM "SALES" WHERE "DATE" = {D '2014-04-01'}` 
 It seems that one should put the letter D to signify that it is a date and not a string/varchar. I hope this helps, even though the question is 1 year old.